# return early in Unit-returning function in Scala

Tags: scala, function

Imagine I have a function in Scala that returns a Unit-value. The function does a certain test at the beginning and concludes that it could stop, i.e. return, already. Is it safe to just put a return statement (without anything) and leave the function?

Comment: why not just use `if/else` rather than dealing with `return`? `if(condition){ ()} else{...continue execution...}`The problem is `return` behaves very weirdly in certain context. It depends on how and where you use that function. This question is impossible to answer until you figure that part out. I would just stick to basic control flow to solve this. You have to write that `if` there anyway, adding `return` will just be dead weight

Comment: Well, if the function returns `Unit` it means it is side-effecting, thus you may do what Sinaspd suggested but no need to add a branch that just returns a `()` rather you add an `if` without an `else` and perform everything inside that. - In any case, is probably that there will be a more idiomatic way to solve the problem you are solving; but without code is not possible to tell.

Comment: This weird behaviour is actually deprecated: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/nonlocal-returns.html

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt: There is no mention of non-local `return` in nested functions in the question and no indication that is what is being asked about. By all accounts, the OP is just asking for a standard *guard clause* style early `return`.

Comment: Well, I didn't say `return` was deprecated (though it should be, as it doesn't serve any purpose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imperative side-effecting code is mostly non-idiomatic in Scala, so you won't find any guidance about exactly *how* to write imperative side-effecting code in Scala.

It sounds like you are talking about a typical *guard clause* style like

```scala
def procedureWithGuard(): Unit =
  if nothingToDo then return
  doTheExpensiveThing()

procedureWithGuard()
```

This is perfectly fine imperative style. It is just not perfectly fine Scala style, but that's not because of the early `return`, but because of the use of side-effects *in general*.

Note that there is a change in Scala 3: in the past, a `return` in a nested anonymous function was `return`ing from the closest lexically enclosing method, i.e. in

```scala
def returnFromNestedFunction: Boolean =
  someCollection.foreach(x => if x % 2 == 0 then return true)
  false
```

both `return`s would `return` from the method `returnFromNestedFunction`, even though the first `return` is actually inside the `apply` method of some automatically generated instance of `Function1[T, Boolean]`. This requires the compiler to jump through some hoops since most of the target platforms supported by Scala (JVM, ECMAScript, and in the past .NET) simply do not support `return`ing from one method in a different method, and they also do not support `GOTO` across methods.

The way this was implemented in Scala was that the inner `return` was compiled into a `throw` of a special exception, and at the place where it returns *to*, the compiler synthesized a corresponding `catch`. However, this has two problems:

1. On all supported platforms, throwing and catching an exception is slow, much slower than `return`. So, while it *looks* like the code would have the performance of a `return` (which is practically free), it actually has the performance of an exception (which is very slow).
2. You can accidentally break the code by having a catch-all exception handler which unintentionally catches the compiler-generated exception.

For this reason, `return`ing from a nested anonymous function is deprecated in Scala 3. Instead, [there is a library](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/util/control/NonLocalReturns$.html) which makes it easy to use the exception throwing trick *explicitly*, so that there is no hidden performance cost (the library makes the exception throwing trick easy to use, but it does not hide the fact that an exception is involved) and you can't accidentally catch a hidden exception you don't know about (because the exception isn't hidden in the first place).

```scala
import scala.util.control.NonLocalReturns.*

def returnFromNestedFunction = returning {
  someCollection.foreach(x => if x % 2 == 0 then throwReturn(true))
  false
}
```

Note that it is not always obvious at first glance that you are `return`ing from a nested anonymous function. In particular, `for`-comprehensions desugar into `foreach` (if there is no `yield`), `map` (if there is a `yield`), or `flatMap` (if there are multiple generators) and `withFilter` (if there is an `if`). For example, this code is actually the same as above, but there is no obviously visible anonymous function:

```scala
import scala.util.control.NonLocalReturns.*

def returnFromNestedFunction = returning {
  for x <- someCollection do
    if x % 2 == 0 then throwReturn(true)
  false
}
```